# error: expression must be a pointer to a complete object type

Tags: c, compiler-errors, mpi

I am trying to write an MPI program in C. And when I tried to compile it use:

```
mpicc -o hw2_b1 hw2_b1.c
```

An error occurred:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv){
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
int N=atof[argv[1]];
int *A, *Ap;
A=malloc(sizeof(int)*(N*N));
Ap=malloc(sizeof(int)*(N*N));

initialize_data(A, Ap, N);

scatter_data(A, N);
mask_operation(A, N, Ap);
gather_results(Ap, N);

MPI_Finalize();
return 0;
```

}
This is my first time to use atof() function, so I don't know what's the problem, even I change the type of N to double, the error still exists.
Any help? Thank you.
The error is pasted below:

```
hw2_b1.c(140): error: expression must be a pointer to a complete object type
    int N=(int)atof[argv[1]];
               ^
hw2_b1.c(140): error: expression must have integral type
        int N=(int)atof[argv[1]];
                        ^
compilation aborted for hw2_b1.c (code 2)
```

Comment: atof[argv[1]] ---> atof(argv[1])

Comment: You *do* know that the `f` in `atof` stands for *float*? If you want to convert to integer, why not use `atoi`?

Comment: Also, extra proofreading *always* help if you get errors.

Answer (score 3):

`atof` is a function, you have to use brackets `( )` for a parameter list, not an index operator `[ ]`. Change `N=atof[argv[1]];` to `N=atof(argv[1]);`. Apart form this `atof` converts a string to a floating point data type (`float`). Your destination data type is `int`. Use `atoi`to convert a string to an integral data type. Adapt your code like this:

```
int N = atoi( argv[1] );
//         ^^         ^
```

Comment: Oh, thanks! My fault, it's a typo. Thank you all the same.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of the square brakets

```
int N=(int)atof[argv[1]];
               ^^      ^^
```

you have to use parentheses

```
int N=(int)atof(argv[1]);
               ^^      ^^
```

Also are you sure that you need to use function `atof` instead of `atoi` that to assign the result to an object of type `int`?

Comment: Oh, god, I finally found the problem. It's my fault! Thanks. It's just a template, and I have to use atof(), thank you.